# Font is not change in webview

Tags: android

```
Typeface hnr = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md.otf");

html ="<html><head><title></title> "
            + "<style type=\"text/css\"> "
            + "body {font-family:"
            + hnr
            + "; } "
            + "</style> "
            + "</head><body ><TABLE>"
            + "<TR>" + "<TD  ALIGN=\"left\" > "
            + "<p><font face='"+hnr+"'>"+ data
            + "</font></p></TD></TR>" + "<TR>" + "</TABLE></body>      
</html>";
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

this is my code but the font is not change when display.

Answer (score 2):

Try using CSS3 font-face rule:

```
html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>\n<head>\n<style>\n"
    + "@font-face { font-family: yourFont; src: url('HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md.otf'); }"
    + "body { font-family: yourFont; }"
    + "</style></head><body>" + data + "</body></html>";
```

Comment: Thanks but i have some douts.. yourFont is string but can i use Typeface  font instead of yourFont coz that is string and typeface is not string..so i think that is not working..pls tell me

Comment: `yourFont` can be any string. More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_fonts.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this 
"p>font size=\"-1\" >YOUR TEXT IS HERE
                +
                "a href=\"#Offline\">View more.. /a>/p>/p/LI>/font>"
and try loadData 
wv.loadData(yourHtmlString, "text/html", "utf-8");


and if you want to set font for page then try this

wv.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(9);

here wv is my webview
```