# (How) can I use native Android fonts in the browser simply by css without web fonts?

Tags: android, html, css, browser, font-family

I'm trying to make a web app without the use of web fonts to keep browser requests at an absolute minimum.

At the same time, I'm trying to use only "good-looking" slim fonts for Headings etc.

This is basically no problem: iOS and Mac OS have HelveticaNeue-UltraLight natively, and Windows (Phone) has Segoe UI (WP) Light.

The fonts do not look the same, but they give a similar overall style and I don't have to use a single webfont. All can be addressed directly via css "font-family".

Is there a way to get a similar appearance on Android? Android has Roboto Light, which would perfectly serve my requirements, but it seems impossible to simply address this via css styles without webfonts.

Comment: Question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22555625/981555

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", "Segoe UI", "Roboto Light", sans-serif;
```

Each OS try use font from this list in course. When the browser finds a font that is present in the system, it will start to use it.  iOS will use the font "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" and ignore other. Android will use the font "Roboto Light" ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! ... But I have tried exactly this, and it does not work. At least not on my Nexus 7 and HTC One (I have tried different browsers on both of them). Unfortunately, Android just uses its default sans-serif font.

Comment: You must know the exact name of the font in the system. The above is just an example

Comment: Yes I know that, I have researched and tried different font names that I found, but it seems impossible to address Roboto via css. (Unless I explicitly include it from an external resource or as a self-hosted web font ... That seems kind of redundant, since Android already has the font installed ... I just can't use it in the browser.)

Comment: Maby this can help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631326/use-roboto-font-in-app-with-minimum-api-level-14 or this http://anton.averin.pro/2012/09/12/how-to-use-android-roboto-font-in-honeycomb-and-earlier-versions/

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
font-family: sans-serif-light;
```

Edit: Apparently, this only works on HTC devices. But it's a start.

Edit2: Looks like Google has changed this with the recent Android 4.4 update, because now it works on my Nexus 7 as well. Not sure about other devices though.

Answer (score -5):

Download `Roboto` and link to it in css like this:

```
@font-face { 
  font-family: 'Roboto Thin';
  src: url('roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I know that, thanks anyway for your answer. My problem is that I want to avoid using css @font-face declarations. This font is installed on every new Android device anyway. So it should be possible to use it WITHOUT having to rely on a web font. But apparently, it is not. (Exception: HTC devices, see my own answer below.)