# Android Wear Recommended Font

Tags: android, wear-os, android-fonts

The Android Wear [UI Toolkit](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#Wear) recommends in multiple places to use "ROBOTO LIGHT CONDENSED" or "Roboto Condensed Light". (In the pdf pages: 11, 14, 16, 17).

However, as far as I can tell, the only default fonts available are the ones [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329907/1047268). Specifically:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
```

From the [typography page](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html), I see that "Roboto Condensed Light" is an actual font.

Is there a way to use this font in Android Wear? Also, any reason why this would not be a default font when it is recommended in the UI toolkit?

Answer (score 4):

I found my answer. [**fonts.xml**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/fonts/fonts.xml) is the definitive list for all system fonts. As mentioned [in another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to/24072492#24072492).

So, for anyone wondering, this is the font mentioned in the UI Toolkit.

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
```