# What is the difference between fontFamily and typeFace in android?

Tags: android

What is the difference between fontFamily and typeFace in android ?
Of course, I read all the description in android developer site, but I'm not clear yet.

According to the general meaning of two words, it should be same meaning.
But in the android xml properties(textview...), it has both properties.
That makes me very confused.

As far as I know....
fontFamily and typeFace is a group of same-look of fonts.(Roboto, Arial)
Font is a specific one of fontFamily.(Roboto-18pt-Bold, Arial-10pt-Italic)

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 19):

To find the answer of your question you have to look into the source code of TextView, you will find its implementation here

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java

Now from the implementation of method `setTypefaceFromAttrs()` it seems like, If you have set `fontFamily` attribute then `typeface` attribute will be ignored.

Also `android:typeface` attribute is added in **api level 1** and using this you can set following fonts

```
- normal
- serif
- sans
- monospace
```

Whereas `android:fontFamily` attribute is added in **api level 16** and this supports more fonts from roboto font family like -

```
- serif
- monospace
- sans-serif
- sans-serif-condensed
- serif-monospace
- sans-serif-smallcaps
```

For more information use below link

[Valid values for android:fontFamily and what they map to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to)