# Inheritance issue, when using property androidTextapperance vs. property style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have a root theme and an inheriting child theme:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorRed">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="colorGreen">#00FF00</color>

    <style name="Root" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />

    <style name="Root.TextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorGreen</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Child" parent="Root">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorRed</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In the manifest file I set the theme `Child`. In the layout I apply the text appearance from the root theme:

```
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="@style/Root.TextAppearance"
    android:text="Hello World!"
```

- Expected: green text
- Actual: red text

How does the `Root.TextAppearance` inherit the color red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Checking the order of precedences

The short answer to the question is, that themes have precedence over `android:textAppearance`.

There are different types of hierarchies for Android. When using the `styles` attribute the styles hierarchy applies as expected. Assuming that the `styles` hierarchy also applies for the `android:textAppearance` attribute obviously fails.

There is another hierarchy for themes. This hierarchy follows down the layout tree. The theme `Child` is applied in the manifest and is the top level.

It seems the settings coming in by this top level theme even overrule the settings of `android:textAppearance` on a lower level. This still feels wrong, as lower levels usually should overwrite higher levels.

So I do some tests by applying the attributes `style`, `android:theme` and `android:textAppearannce` to find out the order of their strengths.

It turns out that `texAppearance` is the weakest and `style` is the strongest:

1. `style`
2. `android:theme`
3. `android:textAppearance`

I think this the explanation why the `theme` from the higher level could overwrite the `android:textAppearance` on the lower level. I admit that I find the low precedence of `textAppearance` rather confusing. It's not how I expected it to work. However, that's the results I found out be testing.

Comment: precedence order mentioned here as well: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/whats-your-text-s-appearance-f3a1729192d

Answer (score 2):

You should set the style not the textAppearance

```
style="@style/Root.TextAppearance"
```

also in styles Root.TextAppearance should have Root as parent

```
<style Root.TextAppearance parent="android:TextAppearance">
```

than set android:textAppearance="@style/Root.TextAppearance" and it should work

Comment: Fact! It works and only works, when I use style. It's a pity I can't use textAppearance to modify the style.

Comment: Give me some time to chose the best of all incoming answers. This one is really useful, but not fully satisfying. I crashes my concept of theming, that strongly depends on the option to modify the style by textAppearance.

Comment: @Blcknx I've edited the answer. It didn't work because your TextAppearance style didn't have a parent. So it wasn't able to inherit the textColor attribute from it.

Comment: Thank you @TibiG. I tried. It does not change the result. I still think it is a bug. It does not inherit the textColor attribute, as I overwrite it. It does inherit five other attributes, I don't make use of.

Comment: @TibiG I think I found out the reason for this behaviour, if it is not a bug. See my answer. What do you think.

Comment: @Blcknx seems legit :)

Answer (score 0):

make some change put color code into color.xml

```
    <color name="colorRed">#FF0000</color>
<color name="colorGreen">#00FF00</color>
```

then after try this..

```
        android:textAppearance="@style/Root.TextAppearance"
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the reason. I put in un purpose into one file, to keep the test case most simple.