# Using different weights of Roboto in modern Android Studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, roboto

I believe having read or heard that Roboto now comes standard with Android Studio and that I no longer need to download the font. So how might I use it in my xml layouts presently? I am particularly interested in using many different weights such as bold, light, thin, etc. So, how might I go about doing that presently? The entire app will use Roboto only. But different TextViews, etc, will have use different weights. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much all your questions are answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to) already.

Comment: @Lamorak Thanks for the link you provided but it seems that I would need api level 16; whereas if I were to download them, then api 10 would work fine. So do you know what gradle or such magic I have to do to get Roboto for API 10 -- without having to download the fonts explicitly myself?

Comment: i.e. is there a support library that makes it possible for APIs older than api-16?

Comment: Maybe there is such library, however, questions seeking libraries are off-topic here (you can do the search as well a I can). Either I would reccomend moving to API 16 or to creating such library yourself. You can dowlnload the fonts easily and then you only need to extend `TextView` to set its own typeface.