# What style would I need for an AlertDialog to bold?

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog, whatsapp

I have an AlertDialog with buttons which I'd like to set to bold. I find the default style to be very thin:

[image]

but when I set the style as such:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/buttonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="buttonStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

I find the result to be, erhm, much bolder than I'd like:

[image]

I was aiming for something like this:

[image]

The screenshot is from WhatsApp. Are they using a different font or is it something I can replicate just by styling my XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to/19692168#19692168),  it seems that the correct style for what I want to achieve is adding these lines to the button style:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
```

Now I have the wanted "not so bold" look!