# Android: set textStyle="medium" for Japanese text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fonts, android-typeface

I am dealing with the Japanese text. I am able to display the English text with medium textStyle by following this link [Android text style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to). However, when I replace the text (which already displayed in medium style) by Japanese, the medium style has gone.

Please let me know if there are other ways to display medium style for Japanese text. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typefacing also needs to be supplied with the Other Styles as well so double check your Japanese Typeface and check if they have other styles like medium, Italic or Bold. The Styles for this cannot be magically set by just the parameter, it also needs the raw Characters files for it. In short, even English characters have Different types of typeface for Bold, Italic etc. The only dynamic that can be set for Typeface that doesn't require the files to be different is the `size` of the text. So if in some cases, you just want to be a little bigger than the normal.

Just use the `textSize` property.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it turns out to be more difficult that I have to download the specific Japanese font which has medium style in order to use it.