# Android version and font support (sans-serif/Roboto)?

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-typeface

I need to know from with version of Android these fonts are supported :

```
sans-serif (Roboto-Regular)
sans-serif-light (Roboto-Light)
sans-serif-thin (Roboto-Thin)
sans-serif-medium (Roboto-Medium)
```

also it's look like that on android 4.4.2 i can't make sans-serif-thin "Bold". any ideas why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These fonts are supported from API 16 - minSdkVersion 16. Here you have related topic: [Valid values for android:fontFamily and what they map to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to)

Here is a link to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html)

So you styles should look like that:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
```

sans-serif-medium (Roboto-Medium) was added in Android Lollipop so that's the reason you can not see changes on 4.4.2 (if you use these fonts).

More helpful links: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/fonts/fonts.xml

And another answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29834998/2065587

Comment: thanks mmbs, but where did you saw that sans-serif-thin were added in lollipop ? i didn't see any doc about this :(