# Android Studio 3.0 Custom font in styles.xml

Tags: android, fonts, android-support-library, android-studio-3.0

I'm unable to set the custom font in my style file.

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/fontTextView</item>
        ...
    </style>

    <style name="fontTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/example</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and I still see default font in my app. But when I change `fontFamily` to one of the default ones, then it changes

```
    <style name="fontTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">monospace</item>
    </style>
```

It also works if I set my custom font programmatically.

```
setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.example));
```

How to make it works for my custom font in `styles.xml`?

I set `compiltSdkVersion` to `26` and `buildToolsVersion` to `26.0.2`. Also I'm using support library:

```
  def supportVersion = '26.1.0'
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
```

My font family:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/example_regular"

    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="300"
    app:font="@font/example_regular"/>

<font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/example_regular"

    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400"
    app:font="@font/example_regular"/>

<font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/example_regular"

    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="700"
    app:font="@font/example_regular"/>

<font
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/example_regular"

    app:fontStyle="italic"
    app:fontWeight="300"
    app:font="@font/example_regular" />

<font
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/example_regular"

    app:fontStyle="italic"
    app:fontWeight="400"
    app:font="@font/example_regular" />

<font
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/example_regular"

    app:fontStyle="italic"
    app:fontWeight="700"
    app:font="@font/example_regular" />

</font-family>
```

I Use the same `*ttf` file for test purpose.

Comment: You sure that your `@font/example` is exist ?

Comment: @Ibrahim Yes. It works if I set it programmatically: `setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.example));`

Comment: You cannot use custom font in style and xml. You need to create custom view or Set it programatically or  use some available libraries like https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: @ArbazRizvi according to this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html I can

Comment: @Lau strange, it's worked for me, you may check if you doing something with your textView xml.

Comment: @Lau Can you share your font-family xml

Comment: You can check this link for font family:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I solve this issue - the reason of this behavior is very simple... I was extending `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 1):

using custom font for xml design :
First you need to create font folder in your resource directory after that
 put all custom font(.ttf file) file in to font folder.
then just add attribute fontFamily in xml design .
Like

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/semibold"/>
```

use that link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html