# How to create custom font family with bold font

Tags: android

I'm trying to create custom font family using this doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html The problem in that that there is no bold attribute and I can not set it programmatically Fonts in XML?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Set 700 as the fontWeight value for your font in bold.

As it's in the [font resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource.html) documentation:

> The most common values are 400 for regular weight and 700 for bold
> weight.

In the lobster font family example you [linked](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) it would be:

```
<!-- bold -->
<font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="700"
    android:font="@font/lobster_bold" />
```

And, if you are using support lib:

```
<!-- bold -->
<font
    app:font="@font/lobster_bold"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="700" />
```

Comment: so I need to create two font families? For normal and bold?

Comment: No, it's one family, you have the <font> element defining the normal, another <font> element defining the italic font and now you should add the bold font also as the other ones (3 <font> elements inside the same <font-family>).

Comment: Note that the fontWeight="700" is what is defining the bold style and not the fontStyle

Comment: Is it still necessary to add both the `app` and `android` prefix? I tried it with only `app` on API 26 and 28 and it still worked.

Comment: Well, it's been a while since I used this code but I've checked it and according to this doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml with the support library only the `app` namespace is needed. I've just edited the answer. You were right, thanks @FlorianWalther

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @jeprubio answer, I should add this that if you are using one font family resource for different font style

> for example you got serif_normal.ttf & serif_bold.ttf fonts and have one font
>   family resource named serif_font.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<font
    android:font="@font/serif_normal"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    app:font="@font/serif_normal"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400" />

<font
    android:font="@font/serif_bold"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="700"
    app:font="@font/serif_bold"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="700" />
```

*for referring to the **bold** weight or **normal** you can use*

> android:textStyle="normal | bold"

*or you can create a custom style like this :*

```
<style name="TextAppearance.BoldFond" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sarif_font</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/sarif_font</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    //another attributes
</style>
```

checkout [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19691530/9636618) for full description.

Answer (score 1):

Download Roboto Font family from
[Google Robot Font URL](https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/apache/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf)

extract the folder and get Roboto-Bold.ttf file and paste this font file in res>font folder.

now you can use this font in xml like this way

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:fontFamily="@font/robot_bold" />
```

You can also set a simple font and set `android:textStyle="bold"` to bold the text

Comment: Link is broken.