# How to apply two different font to a TextView?

Tags: java, android, fonts, textview, styles

My case is same as Android - three sentences, two styles, one TextView. The only difference is that I want to set a Custom Font on the whole text. I have included **roboto Font** as an assets in my project and want to apply that font to the TextView with first part of the text will be **roboto_LIGHT** and middle part **roboto_NORMAL** and remaining part **roboto_LIGHT** again. Any suggestions how it can be done ?

Text needed in following format. Custom text with different styles and single textview.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use some html tags like `<b>` for bold with the following code:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Login to the <b>Web Wallet</b> on PC or MAC"));
```

Then you can define your custom font family as in [How to create custom font family with bold font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264614/how-to-create-custom-font-family-with-bold-font)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/roboto_LIGHT" />
    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/roboto_NORMAL" />
</font-family>
```

The weight 700 is the font for bold style. And then you should apply that created font family to the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fontFamily="@font/my_custom_font"/>
```

Or you can add 3 TextViews in a `ConstraintLayout` and give them some constraints to be in the positions you want otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i wrote exactly what you wrote but the font doesn't change it's showing only normal with bold but doesn't show roberto light

Comment: It seems as it's not loading that font family for whatever reason if you see some text in bold. Try with `app:fontFamily` instead of `android:fontFamily` in the TextView. Or try with both and then if it works you can remove the one which doesn't apply