# How to add font style to textview android kotlin

Tags: android, html, kotlin, fromhtml

I need help, i am stuck in this. My requirement is, I need to add text inside a tooltip. I did that actually. But the text include multiple line text also some lines having bold style other line having regular style with custom font style. By the below code which i am using, i can able to add bold, italic and regular style. But i need to add below custom font style into the text. Please have a look into my below code.

```
textViewToShow.setOnClickListener { view ->

    val tfBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(
        context!!.assets,
        "fonts/myriad_pro_bold.ttf"
    )

    val tfRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(
        context!!.assets,
        "fonts/myriad_pro_regular.ttf"
    )

    var string1 = “Item show in Bold style”
    var string2 = “Item show in Regular style”
    var string3 = “Item show in Regular style with item description”

    val holesTextView = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + string1 + "</b> <br><br> <b><i>"+ string2 + "</i></b> " + string3)
    showToolTip(view, holesTextView)

}

    private fun showToolTip(view: View, holesTextView: Spanned) {
        val builder: Tooltip.Builder =
            Tooltip.Builder(view, R.style.Tooltip)
                .setText(holesTextView)
        builder.show()
    }
```

Any solution/suggestions are highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a [font family](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/myriad_pro_regular" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/myriad_pro_italic" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="700"
        android:font="@font/myriad_pro_bold" />
</font-family>
```

following the answer of [How to create custom font family with bold font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264614/how-to-create-custom-font-family-with-bold-font) for the bold font.

And then you can assign the font family in the layout:

```
<EditText
    android:fontFamily="@font/mycustomfont"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello, World!" />
```

Or Programatically:

```
val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.mycustomfont)
holesTextView.setTypeface(typeface)
```

Or in the case of a [tooltip](https://github.com/tomergoldst/tooltips) using its `setTypeface()` method:

```
val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.mycustomfont)
val builder: Tooltip.Builder = Tooltip.Builder(view, R.style.Tooltip)
    .setText(holesTextView)
    .setTypeface(typeface)
    builder.show()
```

And use [HtmlCompat.fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat) as [Html.fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) is deprecated:

```
val holesTextView = HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<b>" + string1 + "</b> <br><br> <b><i>"+ string2 + "</i></b> " + string3, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Comment: Hi @jeprubio, i am showing it in a tooltip, so when i set the typeface, holesTextView.setTypeface(typeface) is not reachable. I updated my code with tooltip function. Could you plz check it

Comment: Are you using this lib https://github.com/tomergoldst/tooltips ? it has a setTypeface() method. Check my update

Comment: No @jeprubio, https://github.com/ViHtarb/Tooltip. This is the lib i am using

Comment: There is also a .setTypeface() method in there in the Tooltip.Builder, have you checked?

Comment: yea i check that and now it works i guess. Thanks jeprubino :)