# Where to get Fonts available in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, font-family

At the moment I use fonts on my website that works with Chrome for Windows but these fonts does not work with Chrome for Android.

The fonts I would like to use are **Haettenschweiler** and **Impact** but Chrome Browser for Android does not have these fonts. The plain **Arial** font is displayed instead.

To solve this issue it would probably be best to find out exactly what fonts are supported by Chrome for Android and take things from there. I have not been able to find any information on what fonts Chrome supports. What fonts do Chrome for Android support?

Comment: there are fonts (like arial) which are available everywhere since they are preinstalled on the operationg system. Everything else needs to be loaded or it wont be available for your app.

Comment: See also available fonts listed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24072492/1066234

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These fonts probably work on your Windows because you have them installed on your computer. To support custom fonts for everyone (and your other devices), you must load them in your website.
The fonts you provided are licensed fonts, and as far as I know these require you to pay money to use them legally. So for my example I'll use [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Roboto).

Remember that after loading a font, you still have to apply them in your css:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

### External Fonts

External fonts are fonts hosted on external websites, imported in your own. A great place to find free external fonts is [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com).
There are two ways to import external fonts.

You can either import it inside your HTML's head like so:

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Or inside your CSS using `import` like so:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
```

### Internal fonts

Internal fonts are hosted by yourself. You would have to host the font files on the website, and use the `font-face` rule to load them like so:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: url('roboto.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('roboto.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('roboto.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('roboto.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('roboto.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haettenschweiler isn't included in Chrome it is probably in your file system and this is why you can see it. The browsers can use the fonts used in your system or the customly supplied fonts; we call it `web font-kits`.

To use Haettenschweiler You need to buy the webfont kit to use it. You can find it [here](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ascender/haettenschweiler/).

You can find multiple web font-kits in websites like [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) and [Font squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/).