# How to specify Roboto Condensed in CSS for Android devices?

Tags: android, css

I want to style some HTML with a condensed font. I want to use **built-in fonts**, not webfonts. For Apple devices, I can just write `font-family: AvenirNextCondensed-Medium`, but on Android, declarations like `font-family: "Roboto Condensed"`, `font-family: Roboto-Condensed` or `font-family: RobotoCondensed` don't work, even though Roboto Condensed is preinstalled on Android.

I also tried specifying `Roboto` and using `font-stretch: condensed`. No dice.

Is there any way to write my CSS so that Android devices use their built-in Roboto Condensed font?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:

You have to use the nonstandard `sans-serif-condensed` keyword, like so:

```
h1 { font-family: AvenirNextCondensed-Medium, HelveticaNeue, sans-serif-condensed, sans-serif; }
```

Note that `sans-serif-condensed` has to come before `sans-serif` and any other font names recognized by Android. For example, if you put `Arial` before `sans-serif-condensed`, Android will just use Arial (or actually its substitute for it).

For other versions of Roboto (Thin, Light, Medium, etc.), the font names listed in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691530/valid-values-for-androidfontfamily-and-what-they-map-to) should probably work.